# Remove trailing nil values from array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have an array something like this:

```
[["a", nil, nil, nil], ["b", nil, "c", nil], [nil, nil, nil, nil]]
```

I want to remove all trailing nil values from array in ruby.

I tried `arr.map {|x| x.pop until x.last}` but the problem with this approach is that when all the value of arrays are nil like in 3rd array in given array, the loop stucks.

Because of the `until x.last` condition, If all the values are nil then the map function should return me an empty array?

What should be the conditions for this.

The output should be

```
[['a'],['b','nil','c'],[]]
```

Remember I just want to remove trailing `nil` values not in between.

Comment: Should in-between `nil` values really be converted to `'nil'` strings?

Answer (score 14):

For this you can forget about the outer array and solve it for just the inner arrays, then use `map` to apply the solution to all of them.

[`drop_while`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-drop_while) will return a new array without all leading items that met some condition (e.g. `nil?`). You wanted trailing however so combine with `reverse`.

```
[nil,nil,5,nil,6,nil].reverse.drop_while(&:nil?).reverse
[nil, nil, 5, nil, 6]
```

Then use map for all the arrays.

```
arr = [["a", nil, nil, nil], ["b", nil, "c", nil], [nil, nil, nil, nil]]
arr.map{|a| a.reverse.drop_while(&:nil?).reverse}
[["a"], ["b", nil, "c"], []]
```

If you do want any remaining `nil` to actually be a string, you could combine it with another map performing any such conversion you like.

Answer (score 10):

You are on the right way, but just modify your code a bit:

```
array.each { |e| e.pop until !e.last.nil? || e.empty? }
#=> [["a"], ["b", nil, "c"], []]
```

It's faster than using `reverse`-`reverse` and `drop_while`.

Comment: I guess the key point is if mutating the original is desired or not. Allthough a copy + pop might still be faster, true.

Answer (score 4):

One more option is to use `rindex`:

```
arr.map do |e| 
  index =  e.rindex { |i| !i.nil? } # the last index of not `nil` element
  index ? e.first(index + 1) : e 
end
#=> [["a"], ["b", nil, "c"], []]
```